Google BigQuery Alter Column Name During Load
I'm loading JSON data into BigQuery. The JSON contains various structs which in turn contain a number of STRING fields. I can parse 99% of what I need, but getting stuck with one of the remaining columns. The reason being that the column name contains both a space and a hyphen. Both of which are a no no in Big Query (until the flexible column naming support goes GA).
Im loading the data in SQL with this kind of approach:
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE <proj>.<dataset>.<tablename> {
    teams_remove STRUCT<team_a STRING, team_b STRING, winning team STRING, losing-manager STRING>
)

That's just an example to show the syntax I'm working with. In this example the third string 'winning team' will fail to parse/load due to the space and the fourth will fail to load die to the hyphen.
Is there any way to rename the column/field at ingestions/loading time?
I cannot pre-process the source data to fix the column names, unfortunately.
Thanks!

Following on from your post, I thought it was a great question and studied and wrote up a medium article here:
https://medium.com/@kolban1/bigquery-external-tables-with-json-data-d36c8d09c465
In summary, one solution is to use the CSV parser and create an external table that says that the JSON files are CSV records where the delimiter will not be found in the data (eg. 0xFF).  From there, you will now have a table of rows where each row is a String corresponding to the JSON text.  Finally, you can create a view over the table where a JSON Parser is applied to generate the extracted fields.

Fabulous work. In the end I arrived at a similar solution. I used a schema which mapped the errant json fields to a JSON type. Then created a view which used json_extract and Jsonpath expressions to create new fields with aliases which conformed to column naming standards. Thanks again!
